# Oracle and SQL Server - different results when comparing date to null

Tags: sql-server, oracle, date, jpql

I have following query in JPQL:

```
select * 
from Record rec 
where rec.validFrom <= :param 
and (rec.validTo is null or rec.validTo >= :param)
```

I know, that there exists only one record in database. If I run it with param = null, on Oracle I get the record back. However if I run it on a SQL Server database, I do not get the record back. Only suspicious part of the query for me is `rec.validFrom <= :param`. I am not asking how to fix the query, I can do that myself. But it seems to me that Oracle and SQL Server  have different approach regarding comparison of date value against null value. I haven't been able to google something useful on this topic, so I want to ask, does anyone have input on this problematic please?

Comment: Can you reproduce it if you insert a literal "NULL" in the SQL code rather than a parameter?

Comment: if I put null into query directly, I get no record on MSSQL and also no record on Oracle. So I guess my question is offtopic and based on incorrect assumption :(

Comment: For Oracle, NULL is equivalent to an empty string 8-(

Comment: Why not using: `COALESCE(rec.validTo, '') = ''` instead of `IS NULL` ? Not good if you have millions of lines, but will work on both environments.

Comment: I've had my fair amount of issues related to client tool choice of data type for parameters. But I can't think so far of a precise scenario that reproduces your issue. Whatever, I think you should edit the question and post some actual client code, not just the SQL query.

Comment: What exact data type is `validFrom` in each case? (Though I still can't think of a circumstance where you *should* get any records back when :param is null, as `rec.validFrom <= null` should be false on both Oracle and SQL Server, I think, whatever the value of `rec.validFrom`...) As @ÁlvaroGonzález says, I think we need to see more code.

Comment: sorry, as I have posted before, question is offtopic. Both Oracle and MSSQL behave the same, they return no record if param is null. My problem was in data on application level, on Oracle param was not actually null. I'll delete the question

Comment: problem was on application level, date passed to query as param on Oracle was not actually null

Answer (score 1):

I don't see an issue with Oracle returning anything when the param is null, as demonstrated from this test case:

```
declare
  v_valid_from date;
  param date;

  procedure test1 (p_date_in in date)
  is
  begin
    for rec in (with record as (select to_date('01/01/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy') validfrom, to_date('01/01/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') validto from dual union all
                                select to_date('01/01/2001', 'dd/mm/yyyy') validfrom, null validto from dual)
                select *
                from   Record rec 
                where  rec.validFrom <= p_date_in
                and    (rec.validTo is null or rec.validTo >= p_date_in))
    loop
      v_valid_from := rec.validfrom;
      dbms_output.put_line('p_date_in = "'||to_char(p_date_in, 'dd/mm/yyyy')||
                           ', v_valid_from = '||to_char(v_valid_from, 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('p_date_in = "'||to_char(p_date_in, 'dd/mm/yyyy')||
                         ', final v_valid_from = "'||to_char(v_valid_from, 'dd/mm/yyyy')||'"');
  end test1;
begin
  test1(param);
  param := trunc(sysdate);
  test1(param);
end;
/

p_date_in = ", final v_valid_from = ""
p_date_in = "01/12/2015, v_valid_from = 01/01/2001
p_date_in = "01/12/2015, final v_valid_from = "01/01/2001"
```